# Uniswap V3: Fetching spot prices documentation seems incomplete

Tags: uniswap, uniswapv3

I'm working on V3 of Uniswap for the first time, and am trying to get the current price of a pool.

I'm using this tutorial page https://docs.uniswap.org/sdk/guides/fetching-prices, which certainly seems to attempt what I wish.

Further, the comments in the method `token0Price` states:

```
 /**
   * Returns the current mid-price of the pool in terms of token0, i.e. the ratio of token1 over token0
   */
```

However, when I call this function, what I receive is:

```
Price {
  numerator: JSBI(8) [
    445412081,   346709960,
    584891573,   611262682,
    360319882,   934240370,
    1035473620,  1369,
    sign: false
  ],
  denominator: JSBI(7) [ 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4096, sign: false ],
  baseCurrency: Token {
    chainId: 3,
    decimals: 6,
    symbol: 'USDC',
    name: 'USD Coin',
    isNative: false,
    isToken: true,
    address: '0xA0b86991c6218b36c1d19D4a2e9Eb0cE3606eB48'
  },
  quoteCurrency: Token {
    chainId: 3,
    decimals: 18,
    symbol: 'WETH',
    name: 'Wrapped Ether',
    isNative: false,
    isToken: true,
    address: '0xC02aaA39b223FE8D0A0e5C4F27eAD9083C756Cc2'
  },
  scalar: Fraction {
    numerator: JSBI(1) [ 1000000, sign: false ],
    denominator: JSBI(2) [ 660865024, 931322574, sign: false ]
  }
}
```

How do I translate this Price objects JSBI arrays into an actual price of the pool?

Comment: Uni's documentation is rather... lacking

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These JSBI objects got a method `toSignificant`, use it to convert the big number into a number literal.

```
// toSignificant(significantDigits?: number, format?: object, rounding?: Rounding): string;

const p = pool.token0Price.toSignificant(6);
```

will return a floating point number with precision of 6 digits.

Comment: Thank you - will look into submitting a PR to the project documentation that adds this.